# C# cs0660 error (implement interface member)

Tags: c#

[image: ISeaGrid Class]

[image: SeaGrid Class]

There is an error message in the SeaGrid class in which i cannot solve. What do i have to do to implement interface member? (as shown in the error message)

Comment: What's the error message?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add the actual code (without all the comments). Your pictures are missing the end of the `SeaGrid` class - so how can we help?....

Comment: you did not implement the ISeaGrid Item prop in SeaGrid, right click on interface in SeaGrid class and implement the interface members explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you need to implement the getter for your property `Item`

```
public TileView Item { 
  get { 
    // code
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface defines a property named `Item` with a `get`.  The error is saying that you have not implemented that property in your class.